# Teradata connections from .Net using DSN

Tags: .net, connection, teradata, dsn

I'm trying to find out ways for calling a stored procedure in Teradata from .Net.

I looked at the question below:
[TD connection setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173084/how-to-set-up-net-teradata-connection-in-c)

But I do not want to put my password in the web.config. I can encrypt it but the web.config needs to be encrypted for each server with MSA key created on that particular server in the cluster to make it work.

Are there any other ways to make it work like using only DSN? Or any other way where I can create an app pool with the service account and pass it to the Teradata for authentication?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@ Page LANGUAGE="VB" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.ODBC" %>

<script runat="server">
sub Page_Load
dim dbconn

dbconn=New OdbcConnection("Dsn=TDD32;")

dbconn.Open()
dbconn.Close()
end sub
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works in my local, but on the server I get following error: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: You have to set the same DSN on the server as well.

Comment: Somehow it worked for 32-bit DSN but was not working for 64-bit one.

Comment: You need to pick a correct ODBC Manager for the correct target.
For 32-bit DSNs use c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe, and for 64-bit DSNs c:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe.